# How to use p:remotecommand in order to update h:inputText value?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, remotecommand

I have a problem using p:remoteCommand to update a h:inputText in jsf page (primefaces ver 1.1). ActionListener method is being called fine, but server response does not have new value to update inputText value. here is jsf code:

```html
    <h:inputText id="nationalIdCeo" value="#{InsertPotentianAgencyManagers.ceoNationalId}" />
<p:remoteCommand name="rc_updateNationalIds" immediate="true"
actionListener="#InsertPotentianAgencyManagers.setNationalIds}" update="nationalIdCeo" />
<h:outputLink onclick="rc_updateNationalIds(); return false;" >update NIs</h:outputLink>
```

and here is backbean related method:

```html
public void setNationalIds(ActionEvent event){
  Integer r = new Random( System.currentTimeMillis() ).nextInt(1000000);
  ceoNationalId = r.toString();
}

public String getCeoNationalId() {
  return ceoNationalId;
}
```

Also I used firebug to gather more information about response. Here is more information:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<partialResponse>
  <components>
    <component>
      <id>form:nationalIdCeo</id>
      <output><![CDATA[<input id="form:nationalIdCeo" name="form:nationalIdCeo" type="text" value="" />]]></output>
    </component>
  </components>
  <state><![CDATA[<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="8EgC7hvJoXWgMHaUZxk5rx66APlnNueyP32ajDxbvc/i5akMf2jX5b2om9fR6WlpZC0i3PIunbrAxQXxMwRdpzSFyU84eV8ygbQsQNq6XkwhToCteAtgw3FDPXnLDGwxTsX9pKGbYknB2FWSo74DqQ==" />]]></state>
  <callbackParams>
    <callbackParam>{"validationFailed":false}</callbackParam>
  </callbackParams>
</partialResponse>
```

Any solution would be appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you remove `immediate="true"` from `p:remoteCommand`?

Comment: Well, at first thank u for your quick response. It seems that updating inputText (unllike outputText) is going to be done only if all required fields are filled. In other word, if there where even one field that does not pass its validation then inputText whould not going to be updated! So my question is now "how can I bypass validation of fields while using p:remoteCommand?".

Comment: Try adding `process="@this"` to `p:remoteCommand`.

Comment: Did not help. Even I used immediate="true" but it not helped either

Comment: @AliShokri Im sure its only your example code but your action listener method is missing the opening brace.  'actionListener="#InsertPotentianAgencyManagers.setNationalIds}"'